# After update on 12.04, right speaker is not working on Asus?

Tags: 12.04, updates, speakers

My speakers were working fine until recent update on Ubuntu 12.04. My right speaker stopped working after update now only left speaker works. Does anyone know how to fix this?

p.s speakers work on Windows.(dual boot)

Regards